# Using Polly to retry after HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, refresh-token, polly

I'm making calls to an external API and want to deal with the event that a call returns an `Unauthorized` `HttpResponseMessage`. When this happens I want to refresh the access token and make the call again.

I'm trying to use `Polly` with the following code:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeGetRequestAsync()
    {
        var retryPolicy = Policy
            .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            .Retry(1, (exception, retryCount) =>
            {
                RefreshAccessToken();
            });

        var result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => CallApiAsync());

        return result;
    }


    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallApiAsync()
    {
        var url = Options.ResourceSandboxUrl;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        SetRequestHeaders(httpClient);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return response;
    }
```

> I put breakpoints on the `ExecuteAsync` statement and in `DoSomethingAsync` - when I step over `ExecuteAsync` `DoSomethingAsync` is not called and control is returned to the function that called `MakeGetRequestAsync`

I don't understand why `DoSomethingAsync` is not called - can anyone help me with what I'm trying to achieve?

I've looked at the Polly documentation & Polly questions on Stack Overflow but I can't figure out what's going on..

Comment: Just to clarify: Whenever you said `DoSomethingAsync` did you mean `RefreshAccessToken`?

Comment: where is ```DoSomethingAsync``` in above code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Polly wiki [officially documents this pattern](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retry-to-refresh-authorization). In particular this is the code snippet suggested:

```cs
var authorisationEnsuringPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) 
    .RetryAsync(
       retryCount: 1, // Consider how many retries. If auth lapses and you have valid credentials, one should be enough; too many tries can cause some auth systems to blacklist. 
       onRetryAsync: async (outcome, retryNumber, context) => FooRefreshAuthorizationAsync(context), 
       /* more configuration */); 

var response = authorisationEnsuringPolicy.ExecuteAsync(context => DoSomethingThatRequiresAuthorization(context), cancellationToken);
```

> The `FooRefreshAuthorizationAsync(...)` method can obtain a new authorization token and pass it to the delegate executed through the policy using `Polly.Context`.

Answer (score 12):

To use `ExecuteAsync()` you must declare the policy as `.RetryAsync(...)`, not `.Retry(...)`.

If your actual code reads exactly as the code sample above, the `.ExecuteAsync(...)` will be throwing for the mismatch between `.Retry(...)` [a sync policy] and `.ExecuteAsync(...)` [an async execution].  Since this exception is thrown, `CallApiAsync()` is indeed never invoked.  You should be able to see the thrown exception, when calling `MakeGetRequestAsync()`

Overall code approach looks good tho: this retry-refreshing-authentication is a [proven pattern with Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/122)!

Comment: I am using the same retry pattern and getting the exception as "Please use asynchronous-defined policies when calling asynchronous ExecuteAsync (and similar) methods.". I was breaking my head to understand what went wrong..and you saved me. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the game but I leave here a post for future readers. I have created two slightly different solutions for this refresh token with retry problem.

#### Retry policy, Delegating Handler and Custom exception

- Here is sequence diagram which depicts the communication flow
- Here is the [full source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73123449/13268855)

[image: refresh token in case of 401]

#### Retry policy, Delegating Handler and Polly.Context

This version separates the responsibilities in a different way:

- Here is sequence diagram which depicts the communication flow
- Here is the [full source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73247376/13268855)

[image: refreshing token]

Answer (score -1):

this is how async await work in .net, when the execution of your code reaches an `await`, two things will happened

1. the current thread of your code should release to make your code async, that means, your method should return
2. when the task you await is complete, your method should continue from where it used to be

Comment: Thanks, how do I write this code to do what I want?

Comment: All this is true about async executions, but none of it is relevant to why the user's call to `CallApiAsync()` wasn't being made through Polly.