# Refresh Token using Polly with Named Client

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, refresh-token, polly

I have a policy that looks like this

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(resp => resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, 
        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
        onRetry: (resp, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
            // not sure what to put here
        });
```

Then I have a named client that looks like this

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://some-url.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        client.Timeout = 30000;
    })
    .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy);
```

I need to refresh the bearer token on the http client in the event I receive a 401. So in a perfect world the following code would do exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(resp => resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, 
        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
        onRetry: (resp, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
            var newToken = GetNewToken();
            
            //httpClient doesn't exists here so I need to grab it some how
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", newToken);
        });
```

I have read the following articles:

[Re-establishing authentication using Retry](http://www.thepollyproject.org/2017/05/04/putting-the-context-into-polly/)

[Refresh Token using Polly with Typed Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976156/refresh-token-using-polly-with-typed-client)

[retry-to-refresh-authorization](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retry-to-refresh-authorization)

and a couple others as well. However, they all seem use `policy.ExecuteAsync()` which I don't want to use because then I would have to change all the `HttpClient` calls throughout my solution. I'm trying to find a way to simply add this functionality to every request by only changing code in the **StartUp.cs**.

Comment: I think the problem here might be that the policy is (presumably) creating an `HttpMessageHandler`, which is then used to create the `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: @ OP - did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @user3236794 Are you looking for a solution for named client only? Can't you use typed client instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Refresh a token using IHttpClientFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204350/how-to-refresh-a-token-using-ihttpclientfactory)

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: You need to define a communication protocol between a `RetryPolicy`, a `DelegatingHandler` and a `TokenService`.

---

In case of Typed Clients you can explicitly call the `ExecuteAsync` and use the `Context` to exchange data between the to-be-decorated method and the `onRetry(Async)` delegate.

This trick can't be used in a named client situation. What you need to do instead:

- Separate out the Token management into a dedicated service
- Use a `DelegatingHandler` to intercept the `HttpClient`'s communication

This sequence diagram depicts the communication between the different components

[image: refreshing token in case of 401]

#### Token Service

The DTO

```
public class Token
{
    public string Scheme { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

The interface

```
public interface ITokenService
{
    Token GetToken();
    Task RefreshToken();
}
```

The dummy implementation

```
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    private DateTime lastRefreshed = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Token GetToken()
        => new Token { Scheme = "Bearer", AccessToken = lastRefreshed.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}; 

    public Task RefreshToken()
    {
        lastRefreshed = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The registration into the DI as Singleton

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
    ...
}
```

#### Delegating Handler

The custom exception

```
public class OutdatedTokenException : Exception
{

}
```

The handler (interceptor)

```
public class TokenFreshnessHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ITokenService tokenService;
    public TokenFreshnessHandler(ITokenService service)
    {
        tokenService = service;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = tokenService.GetToken();
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.Scheme, token.AccessToken);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            throw new OutdatedTokenException();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

- It retrieves the current token from the `TokenService`
- It sets the authorization header
- It executes the base method
- It checks the response's status

  - If 401 then it throws the custom exception
  - If other than 401 then it returns with the response

The registration into the DI as Transient

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
    services.AddTransient<TokenFreshnessHandler>();
    ...
}
```

#### Retry Policy

The policy definition

```
public IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetTokenRefresher(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    return Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .Handle<OutdatedTokenException>()
        .RetryAsync(async (_, __) => await provider.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>().RefreshToken());
}
```

- It receives an `IServiceProvider` to be able to access the `TokenService`
- It performs a single retry if an `OutdatedTokenException` was thrown
- Inside the `onRetryAsync` delegate it calls the `TokenService`'s `RefreshToken` method

Putting all things together

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
    services.AddTransient<TokenFreshnessHandler>();
    services.AddHttpClient("TestClient")
        .AddPolicyHandler((provider, _) => GetTokenRefresher(provider))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenFreshnessHandler>();
    ...
}
```

- Please bear in mind that the ordering of `AddPolicyHandler` and `AddHttpMessageHandler` [matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700841/13268855)
- If you would call the `AddHttpMessageHandler` first and then the `AddPolicyHandler` in that case your retry would not be triggered

Comment: >In case of Typed Clients you can explicitly call the ExecuteAsync and use the Context to exchange data.

Can you share a reference to a code sample using a Typed Client this way? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington I'll try to post a sample code this week.

Comment: Thank you. That will be a good addition to this thread!

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Could you please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833373/refresh-token-using-polly-with-named-client/76571613#76571613

Answer (score 5):

This post contains an alternative version of [my previously suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73123449/13268855).

*I'm posting this as a separate answer (rather than editing the previous one) because both solutions are viable and the other post is already a lengthy one.*

---

#### *Why do we need an alternative version?*

Because the `TokenFreshnessHandler` has too **much** responsibility whereas the Retry policy has too **few**.

If you look at the `SendAsync` method overridden implementation then you can see that it perform some operation on the `request` and on the `response` as well.

If we could make a separation where

- the handler deals **only** with the `request`
- and policy make its assessment on the *response*

then we would end up with a much cleaner solution (IMHO).

#### *How can we achieve this separation?*

If we could use the Polly's **Context** as an *intermediate storage* between the retry attempts then we were able to do this separation. Fortunately the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` package defines two extension methods against the `HttpRequestMessage`:

- [`SetPolicyExecutionContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#L50)
- [`GetPolicyExecutionContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#L29)

These are under-documented features. On the docs.microsoft I could not even find the related pages. I have only found them under the [dotnet-api-docs repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/2238750cc696339f0a8f04c786f7fe03b14e51ec/xml/Polly/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.xml).

These can be useful if we [know that the `AddPolicyHandler` attaches a new `Context` to the request only if it did not have one already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555484/13268855). Unfortunately, this is *yet again* [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), so it is an implementation detail which might change in the future. But currently we can rely on this.

#### *How will this change the protocol?*

[image: refreshing token]

As you see only difference here is the usage of the `Context`.

#### *How should we change the handler?*

```
public class TokenRetrievalHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ITokenService tokenService;
    private const string TokenRetrieval = nameof(TokenRetrieval);
    private const string TokenKey = nameof(TokenKey);
        
    public TokenRetrievalHandler(ITokenService service)
    {
        tokenService = service;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var context = request.GetPolicyExecutionContext();
        if(context.Count == 0)
        {
            context = new Context(TokenRetrieval, new Dictionary<string, object> { { TokenKey, tokenService.GetToken() } });
            request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(context);
        }

        var token = (Token)context[TokenKey];
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.Scheme, token.AccessToken);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

- I've changed the name of the handler since its responsibilities have changed
- Now, the handler's implementation only cares about the `request` (and does not care about the `response`)
- As it was said previously: the `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` creates a new `Context` if there wasn't any

  - Because of this the `GetPolicyExecutionContext` does not return `null` (even for the very first attempt) rather than a `Context` with an empty context data collection (`context.Count == 0`)

#### *How should we change the policy?*

```
public IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetTokenRefresher(IServiceProvider provider, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .HandleResult(response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        .RetryAsync(async (_, __) =>
        {
            await provider.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>().RefreshToken();
            request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(new Context());
        });
}
```

- Rather than triggering the policy for a custom exception, now it triggers in case of 401 response's status code
- The `onRetryAsync` has been modified in the way that it clears the attached context of the `request`

The registration code should be adjusted as well

```
services.AddHttpClient("TestClient")
    .AddPolicyHandler((sp, request) => GetTokenRefresher(sp, request))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenRetrievalHandler>()
```

- Now, we should pass to the `GetTokenRefresher` method not just the `IServiceProvider` but also `HttpRequestMessage` as well

#### *Which solution should I use?*

- This solution offers nicer separation but it relies on [an implementation detail](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L109)
- The other solution makes the handler *smart* whereas the policy *dumb*

Comment: Would be nice if we can get all this goodness in a nupkg ;-)

Comment: @frankhommers Maybe one day I will create a [polly contrib](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib) for this :P

Comment: One more question about this I know when the token is expired, and I would like to refresh it instead of relying on an Unauthorized. Where would you implement this logic?

Comment: @frankhommers Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: OK: If I know when my token is expired, we are still firing a request to get an Unauthorized back. But in that case I would like to refresh the token beforehand.

Where would you put that logic?

Comment: @frankhommers Ohh okay, I think I get it. My above solution is reactive. It assumes that the token is valid, but if it is unvalid then it reactions on that. Your approach is proactive, for that you don't need polly at all, just refresh the token and then execute the downstream call with the refreshed token.

Comment: But I want both and a transparent HttpClient. I guess I'll expand TokenService with a method EnsureValidTokenAsync() or something like that.

Comment: @frankhommers Yepp, that could be a good place for that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As it was asked by [Chris Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1476321/chris-harrington) let me present here yet another variant: using typed HttpClient

> In case of Typed Clients you can explicitly call the `ExecuteAsync` and use the `Context` to exchange data between the to-be-decorated method and the `onRetry(Async)` delegate.

The good news is that we don't need to use `Context`. We can have a solution which does not require us to populate, propagate and fetch context data.

As always let's start with a sequence diagram:
[image: refresh token with typed client]

- As you can see we don't have a `DelegatingHandler` component here

  - Because the retry is defined and used inside the typed client

#### Token Service

This component is exactly the same as in the other two variants.
So, I will not copy here the dummy implementation.

#### Typed Client

```
public interface IClient
{
    Task<string> GetAsync(string url);
}
```

```
public class Client : IClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
    public Client(HttpClient client, ITokenService tokenService)
      => (_client, _tokenService) = (client, tokenService);

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        var response = await GetRetryPolicy().ExecuteAsync(() =>
        {
            var token = _tokenService.GetToken();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = new Uri(url) };
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.Scheme, token.AccessToken);

            return _client.SendAsync(request);
        });
            
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
    => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        .RetryAsync((dr, _) => _tokenService.RefreshToken());
}
```

- We have defined a retry policy (`GetRetryPolicy`) which triggers for 401 and calls the `RefreshToken` before the next attempt
- The `HttpClient` call is wrapped into the previous policy

  - First we retrieve the current token from the `TokenService` then we set it to the appropriate request header
  - We issue the request against the downstream and we are returning with the result

#### Component registration

This part becomes super simple

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>();
```

And that's it. `IClient` implementation is ready to be used :)

Comment: Thanks. I'd say IClient is "almost" ready to use. Both the IClient and the ITokenService need to be made resilient with Polly.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington "ready to be used" does not mean production ready :P BTW if you have found my work useful then please consider to support me by upvoting.

Comment: No offense intended. Was just thinking out loud about what I have to do next. I'd be interested in sponsoring an effort on your part to make such a sample.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Next steps for `TokenService`: guard `RefreshToken` to execute only once if the token is expired, add resilience strategy for the token retrieval api call, expose metric about token refresh frequency, depending on the requirements generalize the token handling to support multiple tokens for different services/scopes...

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Next steps for `Client`: add resilience strategy (global timeout > retry > circuit breaker > local timeout) for idempotent service calls, add error handling for non-retriable errors, do not expect the `url` as a parameter rather hard code it into the typed client, utilize trace ids to support distributed tracing, etc.