# Polly policy not working using "AddPolicyHandler"

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, refit

I have an application that makes a request for an authenticated service, where it is necessary to pass the `access_token`.

My idea is to use Polly to retry if the `access_token` is expired.

I'm using Refit (v5.1.67) and Polly (v7.2.1) in a .NET Core 3.1 application.

The services are registered as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<ExampleDelegatingHandler>();

IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<ApiException>()
    .RetryAsync(1, (response, retryCount) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Polly Retry => Count: {retryCount}");
    });

services.AddRefitClient<TwitterApi>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/");
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<ExampleDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddPolicyHandler((sp, req) =>
    {
        //this policy does not works, because the exception is not catched on 
        //"Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler" (DelegatingHandler)
        return retryPolicy;
    });
```

```
public interface TwitterApi
{
    [Get("/2/users")]
    Task<string> GetUsers();
}
```

```
public class ExampleDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Why do not catch the exception?
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The retry policy is not working!

Analyzing the problem, I realized that the exception is not being caught inside the HttpClient's `DelegatingHandler`. Since the `AddPolicyHandler` statement is generating a `DelegatingHandler` (`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`) to execute the policy and the exception is not caught there, the policy never executes. I realized that the problem only occurs in asynchronous scenarios, where the request can be sent. In synchronous scenarios it works (example: timeout).

**Why the exception is not caught inside `DelegatingHandler`??**

I am attaching an example project simulating a Twitter call.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1797rq1pbjvcls/ConsoleApp2.zip?dl=0

**External references:**

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#using-httpclientfactory

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingASPNETCore21sHttpClientFactoryWithRefitsRESTLibrary.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Is there any particular reason why did you register a custom `MessageHandler`?  Also you can simplify the `AddPolicyHandler` call by passing the policy itself : `.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy);`

Comment: Peter, this is what I want (to use AddPolicyHandler). I registered a custom MessageHandle only for didactic purpose. AddPolicyHandler behide the scenes register a message handle (PolicyHttpMessageHandler). My point is that the exception is not caught there, so the policy is never executed.

Answer (score 47):

I had an issue involving .NET 5 >= with Polly and HttpClient, which the compiler showed: **HttpClientBuilder does not contain a definition for AddPolicyHandler**.
I could fix it when I changed the Nuget Package`Polly.Extensions.Http` to `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`, I know that isn't the same situation reported here but it might be useful for other people who have come here to find this answer, like me.

Comment: Very useful indeed! Exactly the issue I was having, thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot this helped me as well u da man

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: The ordering of `AddPolicyHandler` and `AddHttpMessageHandler` does matter.

---

I've recreated the problem with `HttpClient` (so without Refit).

#### Typed HttpClient for testing

```cs
public interface ITestClient
{
    Task<string> Get();
}

public class TestClient: ITestClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    public TestClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var resp = await client.GetAsync("http://not-existing.site");
        return "Finished";
    }
}
```

#### Controller for testing

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITestClient client;

    public TestController(ITestClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        return await client.Get();
    }
}
```

#### DelegateHandler for testing

```cs
public class TestHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            _ = ex;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Ordering #1 - Handler, Policy

#### Startup

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddTransient<TestHandler>();
    services.AddHttpClient<ITestClient, TestClient>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<TestHandler>() //Handler first
        .AddPolicyHandler(RetryPolicy()); //Policy second
}

private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> RetryPolicy()
    => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .RetryAsync(1, (resp, count) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resp.Exception);
    });
```

#### Execution order

1. `TestController`'s `Get`
2. `TestClient`'s `Get`
3. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `try`
4. `RetryPolicy`'s `onRetry`
5. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `catch`
6. `TestController`'s `Get` fails with `HttpRequestException` (inner: `SocketException`)

So, here the retry policy does not fired.

### Ordering #2 - Policy, Handler

#### Startup

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddTransient<TestHandler>();
    services.AddHttpClient<ITestClient, TestClient>()
        .AddPolicyHandler(RetryPolicy()) //Policy first
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<TestHandler>(); //Handler second
}

private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> RetryPolicy()
    => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .RetryAsync(1, (resp, count) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resp.Exception);
    });
```

#### Execution order

1. `TestController`'s `Get`
2. `TestClient`'s `Get`
3. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `try`
4. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `catch`
5. `RetryPolicy`'s `onRetry`
6. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `try`
7. `TestHandler`'s `SendAsync`'s `catch`
8. `TestController`'s `Get` fails with `HttpRequestException` (inner: `SocketException`)

So, here the retry policy has been fired.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Why

At the time policies and delegating handlers are executed, a failed HTTP response is not an exception yet. It's just an instance of `HttpResponseMessage` with an unsuccessful status. Refit converts this status into an exception as the very last step in the request-response processing.

#### 2. Order

As correctly noted in [Peter Csala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700841/213376), order matters. When a request is made:

1. Refit serializes the parameters into an `HttpRequestMessage` and passes it to `HttpClient`
2. `HttpClient` does initial preparations
3. `HttpClient` runs the request messages through the handlers and policies in the order they were added to  the client
4. The resulting message is sent to the server
5. Server's response is converted to a `HttpResponseMessage` object
6. This object bubbles up through the same sequence of handlers and policies but in reverse order
7. `HttpClient` does final processing and returns the result to Refit
8. Refit converts any errors into `ApiException`s

Therefore a retry policy will re-run everything that was added after it, but whatever was before it will be executed only once.

So if you want your `access_token` to be re-generated on every retry, the delegating handler that creates the token must be registered *after* the retry policy.

#### 3. How

The easiest way to retry on HTTP failures is to use `HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()` from `Polly.Extensions.Http`. Otherwise you'd have to check for all the failure HTTP status codes yourself. The benefit of `HandleTransientHttpError` is that it only retries on failures which makes sense to retry, like 500 or socket errors. On the other hand it will not retry a 404 for instance, because the resource is not there and is unlikely to reappear if we try again.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and helped me to solve the issue I was running into. I was trying to handle the `ApiException`, not realizing this was too late to the game. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think if we change the policy

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<ApiException>()
    .RetryAsync(1, (response, retryCount) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Polly Retry => Count: {retryCount}");
    });
```

to

```
.HandleResult(x => !x.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

or

```
.HandleResult(x => _retryStatusCodes.Contains(x.StatusCode))
...
private static readonly ISet<HttpStatusCode> _retryStatusCodes = new HashSet<HttpStatusCode>
        {
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
            HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout,
        };
```

then it should work.

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>

.HandleResult(x => _retryStatusCodes.Contains(x.StatusCode))
.RetryAsync(1, (response, retryCount) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Polly Retry => Count: {retryCount}");
});
```

Maybe Refit checks status code and throws ApiException on some later stage