# Polly log all requests with URL, Headers, Content and Response

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I have a project that calls many rest APIs from other projects, and I have some problems to identify not only errors from those APIs but also correct responses but the information is not correct on the other system.
I did this part, but it only log the retry and I need to log the success also.

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>("AuthClient", x =>
    {
        x.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAn);
    }).AddPolicyHandler((services, request) => 
    HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync(
    new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    },
    onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
    {
        services.GetService<ILogger>()
            .LogWarning("Delaying for {delay}ms, then making retry {retry}.", timespan.TotalMilliseconds, retryAttempt);
    }));
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a concern of a policy handler. Try a delegating handler.

Comment: Thanks @crowcoder, If you can give an example I set this as answered.

Comment: [Here is some info](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onRetry` method is executed only if there was an error, which is handled by the policy.
The`HandleTransientHttpError` triggers the policy

- either when there was a `HttpRequestException`
- or when the response code is either 408 or 5xxx.

To inject a logic which should be executed in every situation you need to make use of a custom `DelegatingHandler`. This extension point let's you inject custom code into the HttpClient's pipeline ([1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers)).

Here is a naive implementation of a `LoggerHandler`:

```cs
class LoggerHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggerHandler> _logger;

    public LoggerHandler(ILogger<LoggerHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            _logger.LogInformation(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Request has failed after several retries");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

- As you can see we have injected the logger into the handler

  - In case of flawless downstream request we log some fact on Information level
  - In case of faulty downstream request we log the exception on Error level

Now, let's wire up all the things:

```cs
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync(
    new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    });

services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>("AuthClient", x => { x.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAn); })
    .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggerHandler>();
```

Please bear in mind the registration order matters.

- Please check this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700841/13268855) for further details.

---

There are several tiny things that could be improved as well:

- You don't have to specify the name for the `HttpClient`, because you are using Typed-Client.

  - `services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>(x => ...)`
- I highly recommend to use better naming than `IClient` and `Client`. Image a situation that you need to add one more client to your app. How would name that? `AuthClient` might be a better name:

  - `services.AddHttpClient<IAuthClient, AuthClient>(x => ...)`
- I would also encourage you to use [jitter](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry-with-jitter) to add randomness for your retry sleep duration. If all of the clients try to perform the retries against the overloaded server then it won't help the downstream.

  - Try to distribute the retries with jitter.
- I also suggest to read this [article](https://cm.engineering/transient-timeouts-and-the-retry-rabbit-hole-net-4-5-f406cebbf194) about Retry, Timeout and DelegatingHandler.