# How to include a multiline block of code in a lambda expression for Polly ExecuteAsync?

Tags: c#, lambda, polly

I have working code that uses the `ExecuteAsync()` method on a Polly policy (`IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`) to pull data from a web page. I'd like to add some debug logging to it, but so far I am not able to figure out the correct syntax to have this happen unless I wrap both the logging and http call in a separate method, and then call that via `ExecuteAsync`.

This doesn't seem "right" to me, and I feel there is a cleaner or more direct way. I think my issue is that I don't have a complete enough understanding of how `Func<T>` and lambda expressions truly operate to pull this off, as when I wrap things in `{}` I get errors like:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type `Func<CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>`.

This is my original working code:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
HttpResponseMessage result;
var retryPolicy = (IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>)_policyRegistry[RetryPolicyKeyName];

result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
    async cancellationToken =>    
        await httpClient.GetAsync(myUrl, cancellationToken)
    , cancellationToken
);
```

This code produces the "Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type `Func<CancellationToken, Task>` error:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
HttpResponseMessage result;
var retryPolicy = (IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>)_policyRegistry[RetryPolicyKeyName];

result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
    async cancellationToken =>    
    {
        await httpClient.GetAsync(myUrl, cancellationToken);
    }
    , cancellationToken
);
```

This is my "hack" that gets done what I want with an extra method:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestWithLogAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string myUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Requesting from: {myUrl}", myUrl);
    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(myUrl, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}

var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
HttpResponseMessage result;
var retryPolicy = (IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>)_policyRegistry[RetryPolicyKeyName];

result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
    async cancellationToken =>
        await TestWithLogAsync(httpClient, myUrl, cancellationToken)
    , cancellationToken
);
```

Comment: Is this what you want?  [Can a C# lambda expression have more than one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653703/3744182).  If not can you [edit] your question to share the code that generated the *`Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<CancellationToken, Task>`* error?

Comment: I have reviewed that link before posting this one, and I believe I am still missing something. Perhaps it is because I am passing a cancellationToken variable as an input to my lambda? This line was missing from my original submission, but I have added it now.

Thanks for your comment. I have included the error producing code as suggested.

Comment: @RyanKayser Have considered to use [Typed Client with resilient policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)? With that approach a custom [DelegatingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248766/polly-log-all-requests-with-url-headers-content-and-response) can be injected to log everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here:

```
result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
    await httpClient.GetAsync(managementUrl, cancellationToken)
    , cancellationToken
);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
      return await httpClient.GetAsync(managementUrl, cancellationToken);
    }
    , cancellationToken
);
```

Hence this will execute more than one line in the lambda:

```
result = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
      _logger.LogDebug("Requesting from: {managementUrl}", managementUrl);
      return await httpClient.GetAsync(managementUrl, cancellationToken);
    }
    , cancellationToken
);
```

<sub>..though I wasn't quite clear on how `managementUrl` morphed into `myUrl` across your examples, and whether they differ.. I've assumed not</sub>

Comment: You are correct, managementUrl and myUrl do not differ. I've updated the code to be consistent. I also mis-pasted my original code and neglected to include the line:
async cancellationToken =>

When I include the {} as you have suggested, I get this error with a red squiggly under the =>:
"Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<CancellationToken, Task>'".

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code as written? My suggestions definitely feature a `return` - did you miss it out?

Comment: This helped me. Your example did not have my additional cancellationToken in it, but it had the (). What I did was add your () with cancellationToken inside of it like this:
```
async (cancellationToken) =>
```
and everything worked.

I'd love to understand better what is going on. Why does it work without () when I run a single statement, but require () when I use a block?

Thanks for your help! I am marking this as the answer.