# Does the order in which you add handlers matter when registering an HTTP client? - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient, polly

When you are registering an HTTP client in .NET as such

```
return services
            .Configure<Options>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(Options)))
            .AddHttpClient<IService, Service>()
                .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry("Field")
                .AddOAuthHttpMessageHandler(() => configuration.GetBinded<Options>().RealmScope)
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<TrackingHandler>()
                .Services;
```

Does the order in which you add handlers matter? Would it cause an issue to have `AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry` before `AddOAuthHttpMessageHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does the order which you add handlers matter?

- **YES**

See this for Policy handler

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700841/850980

or this for DI services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#jcp

> Would it cause an issue to have "AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry" before
> "AddOAuthHttpMessageHandler"?

I think it depends on further implementation details.