# How can i invoke X-HttpMessageHandlers when retrying requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

**In short:** I want to execute X-HttpMessageHandlers when retrying a request.

**Implementation:** Currently, I have added an HttpClient, whose request gets handled by a Logging- and a PolicyHandler:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly
builder.Services.AddHttpClient()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHandler>()
    .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
```

**Policy:** To keep the policy very simple, let's use an example:

```
public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    // HandleTransientHttpError: Handles HttpRequestException, 
    // Http status codes >= 500 (server errors) 
    // and status code 408 (request timeout)

    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .RetryAsync(3); // Retry the request up to 3 times
}
```

In case you want to test out the retry policy, send requests to: https://httpbin.org/status/503.

The above link will return an unsuccessful HttpResponseMessage with a status code 502, aka Bad Gateway. This response type is a server error, so it will get handled by the policy.

**Sources:**

- **Polly:** https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http/blob/master/README.md
- **HttpBin:** https://httpbin.org/

Comment: What is an "x-HttpMessageHandler"?

Comment: HttpMessageHandler is a decorator class that wraps around the HttpClient's SendAsync method. A common handler is the DelegatingHandler, but there are various handlers that can be used, so check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?view=net-8.0 for more information on the topic.

Comment: But what is the "x-"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR: You just have to change the message handlers registration order

from

```
.AddHttpMessageHandler<LogHandler>()
.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy);
```

to

```
.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
.AddHttpMessageHandler<LogHandler>();
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

In order to better understand why `DelegatingHandler`s' registration order matter I will extend my original post.

### The `AddPolicyHandler`

This extension method basically registers a [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.policyhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instance into the handlers pipeline. This class implements the `DelegatingHandler` abstract class in a way that it applies a policy to the outgoing request. *That's why the policy's type should be `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`.*

The important stuff here is that from the `HttpClient` perspective your `LogHandler` and this `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` are treated in the same way.

### `AddHttpMessageHandler`, `AddPolicyHandler`

If you register the handlers into the HttpClient's pipeline like you did then the output will be:

```
Loghandler
Retry attempt 1
Retry attempt 2
```

Lets see what happens under the hood

[image: wrong order]

I've used [mermaid.js](https://mermaid.js.org/) to draw this diagram and I've used autonumbering to be able to correlate action and emitted output.

```
2: Loghandler
7: Retry attempt 1
10: Retry attempt 2
```

### `AddPolicyHandler`,`AddHttpMessageHandler`

This time lets switch the registration order. The output will be:

```
Loghandler
Retry attempt 1
Loghandler
Retry attempt 2
Loghandler
```

The actions sequence:

[image: good order]

and finally the correlated log:

```
4: Loghandler
8: Retry attempt 1
10: Loghandler
14: Retry attempt 2
16: Loghandler
```

---

For more details please check out [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460681/polly-policy-not-working-using-addpolicyhandler/).

[Here you can find a dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7QcyAo) to be able to play with it.

Comment: Really good answer, was also the implementation we went through with. Sorry for updating the question, it should still fit your answer.

Comment: @GråSkærm I'm glad to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Integrate your logging in the policy. Here is a simple sample.

**Your program**

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => !response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryCount => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            var logHandler = new LogHandler();
            logHandler.LogRetryAttempt(outcome, retryCount);
        });
```

**Your loghandler**

```
public class LogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LogHandler");
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }

    // Add this method to log retry attempts
    public void LogRetryAttempt(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> outcome, int retryCount)
    {
        // Log the details of the retry attempt
        if (outcome.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Retry {retryCount} due to an exception: {outcome.Exception.Message}");
        }
        else if (outcome.Result != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Retry {retryCount} due to a non-success status code: {outcome.Result.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In this particular case you are using multiple `LogHandler`s at the same time. You have also made the `LogHandler` Polly-dependent by using the `DelegateResult` structure.