# Retrieving access token as a part of the Refit execution flow

Tags: c#, polly, refit

I have API similar to this:

```
GET /api/token?key={key}

GET /api/data?key={token}
GET /api/data2?key={token}
```

Before using any other call, I must query the first request and get the token by the fixed key. Then using the thing token, I can make any other query.

Definitely I can define the client as is and in my higher-level logic I can query the token, save it and then pass as an argument, but I'm wondering if it is possible to add transparently, potentially with Polly if needed.

I can create a separate Refit client that can retrieve the token only, and then inject it as a handler to the main client. so whenever I make any call, if I don't have a token, the handler would retrieve a token and pass it.

I'm wondering if there is a more standard way to do so

Comment: It can be achieved via a `DelegatingHandler` and some helper classes. Here I have showed 3 different ways how can you achieve it with refresh capability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833373